# how to pass a string in parm request and loop it in my request path without saving to a file and creating table

Tags: karate

so i created/def a object with

```
And def memeberIDs = $.users[*].id
And print memeberIDs
```

and i get a list like so

```
[
  "eOVbGI0XSiabeiLZtB-ROQ",
  "iK-Fz_NRSbSt-7AdodjDrA",
  "dS2czwVFRZmy8a6oxO7JKw",
  "yxH3bmF3THuCgLWLGh7eeQ",
  "bqD41MgvSlC94EQH-r1H-Q",
  "MrQihYjiR_WmWHA2-Y2cZQ",
  "9N7uZdT_RTmePdJ5DMZ7sg",
  "qo76PFcSS3-61FwgKCz6Ng",
  "tjo3sdj3RMe8RoSBR3U_Ng",
  "OuFxQR7KThCBPv2wHtKzhg",
  "YmQKkv69Ts2yQ32LIjJN-g",
  "A7kRauysQsCtle9G-bMV0g",
  "zinHreHLTluUWdFzavssEA",
  "UhZt8B_JSVaPBAJdIcPBsw",
  "MtT_yR1iQqmDWMWlxXsWmQ",
  "y2c9aK17Qouune_c_ZGlYQ",
  "xGHOe7wxQru-NruIBPHL7Q",
  "sTe8TADNTQ6nmg4UJeXiOQ",
  "qC2FJUJeQJmOJPKkE_iehQ",
  "4V0a93O8TCK-jjDujVVH-A",
  "sk1tDsUmRYWUjyCMWFOqDw",
  "ChmxrwHwTcS9I3u-RveBQA",
  "ZL3uSx1oQbOc2c5qrFYRew",
  "qjxFk-x9SVe-8XkzMbLrBw",
  "7uIQVAXuSVe4tcWdv6S7MQ",
  "V4mdzUj2SpyVpKlJfSdOEg",
  "dU61-sNoQu6Q87hItkGcHw",
  "enhFrWkfTDuaFqQCwPetAw",
  "Txte_5FtTiaSfsc5k7-HmA",
  "7tkMxEglS5qgx6bKObByKg",
  "-uv0OuoNRlinnI4HkGsSSg",
  "tLxWhEqSSiOcqyGJKsG6tQ",
  "8tqnoZ1DQrq0DGzU_4OVmg",
  "E9Rjy2euRbaKeaP1INxvGA",

]
```

My next request looks like

Given url 'https://api.someurl.com/v2/users//meetings?type=all&page_size=30&page_number=1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some time and study this example. And read this part of the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

```
Background:
* def list = ['foo', 'bar']
* def data = karate.mapWithKey(list, 'name')

Scenario Outline:
* url 'http://httpbin.org'
* path 'anything'
* param test = name
* method get

Examples:
| data |
```

This example will make 2 requests,

1) `GET http://httpbin.org/anything?test=foo`

2) `GET http://httpbin.org/anything?test=bar`

Comment: i think i did something is a miss, i tried coping your solution as is and i am getting below error
* dynamic expression evaluation failed: data 0
zzz.feature:12 - javascript evaluation failed: data, ReferenceError: "data" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1

Comment: @unknown yes you have a miss. it works for me. if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: got a little further,  javascript evaluation failed: karate.mapWithKey(list, 'name'), Cannot cast com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap to java.util.List

Comment: @unknown please. see my previous comment. and, it sounds like `list` for you is a JSON object not array. fix that